# Set Excel cell equal to string containing date without leading apostrophe

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some code that's using `.CopyFromRecordset` to write strings to an Excel sheet. This recordset contains strings that look like dates and numbers, like *1* and *09-08-2018*, and these are correctly left as strings.

I've recently added some additional processing that adjusts some cell values. However, when writing values back to the cells, I'm unable to preserve their current state (string, formatting: general, no leading apostrophe).

The following code illustrates my problem:

```
Public Sub MCVE()
    With Range("A1")
        Debug.Print .Value '09-08-2018
        Debug.Print .Value2 '09-08-2018
        Debug.Print VarType(.Value) = vbString 'True
        Debug.Print .NumberFormat 'General
        Debug.Print .PrefixCharacter 'Zero-length string
        .Value = .Value 'I want to manipulate the value here too
        '.Value2 = .Value2 'Yields the same result
        Debug.Print .Value '08-09-2018
        Debug.Print .Value2 '43351
        Debug.Print VarType(.Value) = vbString 'False
        Debug.Print .NumberFormat 'm/d/yyyy
        Debug.Print .PrefixCharacter 'Zero-length string
    End With
End Sub
```

I can manually set the `.NumberFormat` to *@* to force it to text, but then both `.NumberFormat` and `.PrefixCharacter` change, and that causes trouble further along when importing it into another program. I can also pad the string with an apostrophe before assigning it, but that changes `.PrefixCharacter` too.

I've tried using `.Value2` instead of `.Value`, no difference. `.Text` is read-only, so I can't use that for assigning. Setting things like `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` also has no influence.

This seems very trivial, but I've yet to find a working solution after hours of trying.

Comment: Which excel version are you working on  ?

Comment: @ImranMalek Excel 2016, build 8201, 32-bits, but I can repro this in 2010 too.

Comment: if you are trying to input 08-09-2018 as **value** in a cell with `General` format and prevent Excel from automatically converting it to Date, then , in my opinion it's not possible.

Comment: You're importing a DMY text date and your system is clearly MDY. Fix the date import.

Comment: @Jeeped I don't want to import a date at all! It's a string, not a date

Comment: I think the only option is to save formatting, set formatting to text, set vaue, restore formatting.

Comment: @cyboashu I'd agree, but the stupid thing is, I already did just that using `.CopyFromRecordset`. The problem is adjusting it after import, at which I'm failing.

Comment: @BrackNicku That leaves me with an apostrophe at the start of the string, which is throwing off further processing

Comment: If you set the `.NumberFormat` to "@" - no apostrophe.

Comment: @BrakNicku Setting that number format unfortunately adds a leading apostrophe to the string (`.PrefixCharacter` becomes '). If you had a way to avoid that I'd be very interested, the format is not really important.

Comment: For me [this code](https://pastebin.com/W8y70ZyB) does not change prefix - it is blank before and after in Exce 2013.

Comment: @Erik could you update the "further processing" to handle the prefix character?

Comment: @BrakNicku That's certainly strange. You could post it as an answer, since it works for me in Excel 2010, but not in Excel 2016. Not usable for me, but perhaps for future readers. I haven't encountered such incompatibilities before.

Comment: @chrisneilsen That's what I'm trying to avoid, because then I would either need to slap the prefix on everything, or act independent of the prefix.

Comment: That is strange... I do not have access to 2016, so my last idea: I would try a) set the `.NumberFormat` to "@", b) manipulate `.Value` c) call `.ClearFormats`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
Public Sub MCVE()
    Dim OldFormat As String
    With Range("A1")
        OldFormat = .NumberFormat
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = .Value 
        .NumberFormat = OldFormat
    End With
End Sub
```

solves the problem in Excel 2010 and 2013, but (as reported in comments) changes `PrefixCharacter` to apostrophe in 2016.

This version seems to work in all versions:

```
Public Sub MCVE()
    With Range("A1")
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = .Value 
        .ClearFormats
    End With
End Sub
```